# Need help parallel traversing a dag in D

Tags: parallel-processing, d, graph-traversal

Edit: OK, here's a much much simpler example illustrating my problem.  why is only the first task ever put onto the queue?

```
import std.stdio;
import std.parallelism;

void simpleWorker(uint depth, uint maxDepth, TaskPool pool){
    writeln("Depth is: ",depth);
    if (++depth < maxDepth){
        pool.put( task!simpleWorker(depth,maxDepth,pool));
    }
}

void main(){
    auto pool = new TaskPool();
    pool.put(task!simpleWorker(0,5,pool));
    pool.finish(true);
    writeln("Done");
}
```

Original:

I need to traverse this DAG. When I visit a node I clean it.  I can't clean a node until all of its parents are clean.

The way I'm attempting is to have the worker thread's current node check all of its children to see which ones can be processed. Any that can be processed are added to the TaskPool.

My problem is I can't figure out how to add new tasks to the TaskPool and get them processed.  This just cleans the first node in the DAG, and then exits, leaving everything else dirty.

```
void cleanNode(Node node, TaskPool pool){
    node.doProcess();
    foreach (client; node.clients){
        if (client.canProcess()){
            pool.put(task!cleanNode(client, pool));
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    auto dag = mkTestDag(5);
    auto pool = new TaskPool();

    pool.put( task!cleanNode(dag[0], pool));
    pool.finish(true); 

    writeln("\n\nOutput:");
    foreach (d;dag){
        writeln(d);
        writeln(d.dirty ? "dirty" : "clean","\n");
    }
}
```

The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/LLfMyKVp

Comment: Here is a runnable version of your code: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/e6c7418f you can fork it, and run it on the d-paste website easily...

Comment: That's a helpful tool and I'll probably use that for future questions... but do you have any insight on how to make my code work? I'm expecting each of the nodes to print out "clean".

Comment: What you mean by "clean" ? :)

Comment: I mean the string "clean" from this line: `writeln(d.dirty ? "dirty" : "clean","\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because an Error is being thrown from the put inside simpleWorker.

This version shows the error:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.parallelism;

void simpleWorker(uint depth, uint maxDepth, TaskPool pool){
    writeln("Depth is: ",depth);
    if (++depth < maxDepth){
        try {
            pool.put( task!simpleWorker(depth,maxDepth,pool));
        } catch (Error e) {
            writeln("Fail: ", e.msg);
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    auto pool = new TaskPool();
    pool.put(task!simpleWorker(0,5,pool));
    pool.finish(true);
    writeln("Done");
}
```

And the output:

```
Depth is: 0
Fail: Cannot submit a new task to a pool after calling finish() or stop().
Done
```

Hopefully someone else can explain the correct way to use TaskPool.

**Edit**

Got it working by telling the tasks to run like this:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.parallelism;

void simpleWorker(uint depth, uint maxDepth, TaskPool pool){
    writeln("Depth is: ",depth);
    if (++depth < maxDepth){
        try 
        {
            auto subWorker = task!simpleWorker(depth,maxDepth, pool);
            pool.put(subWorker);
            subWorker.yieldForce();
        } catch (Error t) {
            writeln("Fail: (",  typeof(t).stringof, ") ", t.msg);
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    auto pool = new TaskPool();

    auto worker = task!simpleWorker(0,5, pool);
    pool.put(worker);
    worker.yieldForce();

    pool.finish(true);
    writeln("Done");
}
```

Output:

```
Depth is: 0
Depth is: 1
Depth is: 2
Depth is: 3
Depth is: 4
Done
```

Comment: I think the working version removes the parallelism from the code. I'm pretty sure making a task, then forcing it to yield is conceptually the same as calling the function. So I think it's equivalent to single threaded recursion at that point.

Comment: I ran it a few times with various depth levels and it looks like you're right. So, we still need someone to answer with the correct way to use TaskPool to do this. Another way to do it would be to use spawn() to create a new thread for each run of simpleWorker.

Answer (score 0):

You have such behaviour because your `canProcess()` returns false for **all nodes** except the root node. Since `cleanNodeSimple()` calls canProcess() to check whether to put new task to the pool, it never does that I believe...
Check the output of this (modified) program: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/ea0c393a .

EDIT:
Furthermore, after some analysis, the loop is executed only once as well, so nothing is added to the task pool. :)

Code is on [DPaste](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/ea0c393a), check it out. Here is the most interesting part that may help you solve the problem:

```
// Dejan: will be called only once!
// Because canProcess() returns false for all children.
void cleanNodeSimple(Node node, TaskPool pool){
  node.doProcess();
  writeln("cleanNodeSimple() called for node `", node, "`"); 
  foreach (cli; node.clients){
    writeln("I am ", cli, " and I am executed only once, because I am only RootNode's client.");
    if (cli.canProcess()) {
      writeln("I will be executed only once because because ", cli, " has ", cli.clients.length, " clients.");
      writeln("And its master #1 is ", cli.clients[0].masters[0].dirty ? "dirty" : "clean");
      pool.put( task!cleanNodeSimple(cli, pool) );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I first put the root node in the queue. Then in `doProcess()` the root node is cleaned, so its clients should then return `true` for `canProcess()`

Comment: Nope, check the modified code please and you will (hopefully) understand.

Comment: The only thing you did was add line 61 where it prints out when `cleanNodeSimple()` is called.  I know that it only gets called once, but once it's called on the root node, doProcess cleans it so it **should** allow its clients to be added to the queue.  Why doesn't it?

Comment: Darn edit time limit :-/
So I commented out the `canProcess()` check in this version and the new tasks still don't make it onto the queue.
http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/818a5cf0

Comment: Not true, I also commented canProcess(). - How come you do not get it that canProcess() returns false all the time? :) That was the point of my edit, plus read my comment to the canProcess() method. I have modified the example further so you see that it goes through that loop only once. :)

Comment: Look at the code from my previous comment again. Lines 63 and 65.  I don't actually run `canProcess()`.  Also check out the edit to my question with a much simplified version of my problem.

Comment: Yeah, I did, but you did not see the comments in the cleanNode method... Basically the loop is executed only once...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39979/discussion-between-tyler-fox-and-dejanlekic)

Answer (score 0):

to iterate in a parallel fashion you can use `parallel`:

```
foreach (client; pool.parallel(node.clients,1)){
    if (client.canProcess()){
        cleanNode(client, pool);//<- EDIT: no need to make a task here
    }
}
```

this will block until all clients have been iterated over (letting the current thread do some work as well)

to start you need to `force` the first task in `main()` instead of calling finish on the pool

Comment: Hmm, I gave that a try and all I get is a crazy negative shell return and windows starts searching for a way to fix my program's problem.
http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/fork/ea0c393a   (don't actually trust the output from this, copy it onto your machine and run it to see what I mean)

Comment: if you do parallel then you can replace `pool.put(task!cleanNode(client, pool));` with `cleanNode(client, pool);` as parallel already makes it concurrent

Comment: This certainly works for smaller lists, but each thread waits until all of its node's clients recursively finish.  So if I've got my test DAG that's got a depth of say 500, I'll hit a limit.  On my current rig, it hits the limit at between 380 and 410.