# Using worker threads to add new tasks to a taskPool in D

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, d

This a simplification and narrowing to another of my questions: [Need help parallel traversing a dag in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528562/need-help-parallel-traversing-a-dag-in-d)

Say you've got some code that you want to parallelize. The problem is, some of the things you need to do have prerequisites. So you have to make sure that those prerequisites are done before you add the new task into the pool. The simple conceptual answer is to add new tasks as their prerequisites finish.

Here I have a little chunk of code that emulates that pattern.  The problem is, it throws an exception because `pool.finish()` gets called before a new task is put on the queue by the worker thread. Is there a way to just wait 'till all threads are idle or something? Or is there another construct that would allow this pattern?

Please note: this is a simplified version of my code to illustrate the problem.  I can't just use `taskPool.parallel()` in a foreach.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.parallelism;

void simpleWorker(uint depth, uint maxDepth, TaskPool pool){
    writeln("Depth is: ",depth);
    if (++depth < maxDepth){
        pool.put( task!simpleWorker(depth,maxDepth,pool));
    }
}

void main(){
    auto pool = new TaskPool();
    auto t = task!simpleWorker(0,5,pool);
    pool.put(t);
    pool.finish(true);
    if (t.done()){ //rethrows the exception thrown by the thread.
        writeln("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: do `t.workForce()` before calling `pool.finish()` in your main

Comment: That keeps it from throwing an exception (certainly a step in the right direction), But it only makes it through 2 iterations when it should make it through 5.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/eb9e4cfc

I changed to for loop to:

```
void cleanNodeSimple(Node node, TaskPool pool){
    node.doProcess();
    foreach (cli; pool.parallel(node.clients,1)){ // using parallel to make it concurrent
        if (cli.canProcess()) {
            cleanNodeSimple(cli, pool); 
            // no explicit task creation (already handled by parallel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it that way blocks each thread until all subthreads are completed. That means it recursively creates new threads without allowing the old ones to terminate. So doing that with a large depth will cause some kind of overflow.

Comment: no, the calling thread will also do work on each foreach call (at least that's what my analysis of std.parallelism tells me)

Comment: Check out this version of the code: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/667b9c5d
Notice that all of the nodes are cleaned before any of the parallel foreach iterations finish.  If I bump the DAG size up to 500 on my local machine, it crashes. However it seems to happily continue on the dpaste server.

Comment: check which thread does the cleaning, chances are it's the calling thread most times